# US Citizen sending money overseas

Tags: united-states

I would like to send money to my family back home to help them purchase home. And I have a few questions to this regard:

1. Is there a limit on how much I can send? Can I send $100K plus?
2. What is the most appropriate way to send money - international wire? Is there international-wire limit restrictions I need to be aware of?
3. Is there any tax obligation should I be aware of when sending money home?
4. If my family can return my money back in future, great, if not I really don't care, but when (if) I get my money back, will I have to pay taxes on bringing my own money back into US?
5. Is there anything else do I need to be aware of?

fyi, my family isn't US citizens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a limit on how much I can send? Can I send $100K plus?

No. Yes.

> What is the most appropriate way to send money - international wire?
>   Is there international-wire limit restrictions I need to be aware of?

Yes. No.

> Is there any tax obligation should I be aware of when sending money
>   home?

If you're a US tax resident (which, as a US citizen, you are), you should be aware of [gift tax rules](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Frequently-Asked-Questions-on-Gift-Taxes). You'll probably want to talk to a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your state) and/or attorney, to understand the ramifications in full.

> If my family can return my money back in future, great, if not I
>   really don't care, but when (if) I get my money back, will I have to
>   pay taxes on bringing my own money back into US?

No. But if you're giving it as a loan - you'll get paid interest which is taxable income to you.

> Is there anything else do I need to be aware of?

The rules of the country which you're sending the money to.

Comment: To clarify, to count as a loan, and not a gift, you need to charge some reasonable interest rate. *But*, you can gift the interest, which should be less than the amount of the loan itself (and at some point, you can gift the remaining principal to "cancel" the loan).